# Rails issue - undefinded method 'name'

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

for some reason this page wont opening using ruby on rails 5. Its giving me a undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass error.

The code was working perfectly the last time i opened it. can anyone please help? It would be very much appreciated.

here the the view page.

```
<h1> Your sale history page </h1>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th>Image</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Label</th>
    <th>Condition</th>
    <th>Customer</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Date Sold</th>
  </tr>

    <% @orders.each do |order| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= image_tag order.record.image.url(:thumb)%></td>
      <td><%= order.record.Title %></td>
      <td><%= order.record.Label %></td>
      <td><%= order.record.Condition %></td>
      <td><%= order.buyer.name %></td>
      <td><%= order.record.Selling_Price %> </td>
      <%#THE BELOW CODE IS FOR RUBY DATE. FOUND ON rubydoc%>
       <td><%= order.created_at.strftime("%-d %B, %Y") %></td>
       <td>

    </tr>
<%end%>
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
#the below code validates that the name present
  validates :name, presence: true

#the below code tells rails that a user has many records. and that if a user is deleted so is the record
  has_many :records, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :sales, class_name:"Order", foreign_key: "buyer_id"

  has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy
end


class Order < ApplicationRecord
  #the below validates the form fields
  validates :address,:town_or_city,:state_or_county,:post_or_zip_code,:country, presence: true

  belongs_to :record

  # the below code tells rails that the relationship is two sided. a user can be a buyer or a seller
  belongs_to :buyer, class_name:"User"
  belongs_to :seller, class_name:"User"
end
```

Comment: Looks like `order.buyer` is returning `nil` (instead of returning a `buyer` instance). This is may be happening for a number of reasons. Are you sure that every `order` has a `buyer` related to it?

Comment: yea, they are related to the table. This was working perfectly yesterday. Ive no idea why its now causing an error!

Comment: Could you post the relevant parts of the `Order` and `Buyer` models, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I guess you need quick fix put

```
   <td><%= order.try(&:buyer).try(&:name) %></td>
```

this will make sure you do not get error if ther is no buyer than see witch order is without buyer

Comment: Thank you very much, This has solved the problem! maybe one of the items sold was connected to a account that i deleted?

Comment: glad I could help we all been there :)

Answer (score 0):

Does `order` table have `buyer_id` on all records?

Maybe, there are records where `buyer_id` is null.
Or `order` can't get `buyer` because there isn't matching id.

Answer (score 0):

I found below link useful to know more about 'try' usage and why 'try' is better over rescue nil option in the above scenario.

https://rubyinrails.com/2015/08/27/rescue-nil-in-ruby-on-rails